# Phoenix 4.8 Issue

Tags: apache-phoenix

I have Phoenix 4.8  and hbase 1.2; I have copied jars : phoenix-core-4.8.0-HBase-1.2.jar and phoenix-4.8.0-HBase-1.2-client.jar in the hbase/lib folder.
On starting .sqlline.py ; I am getting following error :

Error: ERROR 2007 (INT09): Outdated jars. The following servers require an updated phoenix.jar to be put in the classpath of HBase: region=SYSTEM.CATALOG,,1470746624029.8eaa1de436397c886fd7c5e4009c1a82., hostname=impetus-n310u,16201,1471850762175, seqNum=99 (state=INT09,code=2007)
java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 2007 (INT09): Outdated jars. The following servers require an updated phoenix.jar to be put in the classpath of HBase: region=SYSTEM.CATALOG,,1470746624029.8eaa1de436397c886fd7c5e4009c1a82., hostname=impetus-n310u,16201,1471850762175, seqNum=99
    at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionCode$Factory$1.newException(SQLExceptionCode.java:454)
    at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionInfo.buildException(SQLExceptionInfo.java:145)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.checkClientServerCompatibility(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1228)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.ensureTableCreated(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1063)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.createTable(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1396)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTableInternal(MetaDataClient.java:2302)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTable(MetaDataClient.java:922)

[AS PER PHOENIX DOCUMENTATION THESE VERSIONS ARE COMPATIBLE ; BUT STILL GETTING THIS ISSUE; ONE MORE THING PHOENIX-HBASE-MINIMAL-....JAR IS NOT IN THE 4.8 DISTRIBUTION OF PHOENIX; AS IT WAS IN OLDER VERSIONS; I WILL APPRICIATE ANY HELP REGARDING THIS ISSUE]

Answer (score 2):

For 4.8, as far as I know, you need only put `phoenix-[version]-server.jar` into hbase lib path. The `phoenix-[version]-client.jar` should not be put there, instead it is supposed to be put at client side, used along with jdbc. See [Phoenix installation doc](http://phoenix.apache.org/installation.html).

Comment: Hi did you resolve this issue. If yes, can you please help me out  in more detail. I tried but i didnt works for 5.0

Answer (score 0):

We were doing some basic benchmarking of Phoenix to validate their TPC-H claims on the 4.8 release.  Needless to say, it was painful.

I think the install doc did not get updated for 4.8.  We saw issues around needing both core and server jars on HBase for it to work but we did not try to upgrade.  There were missing Tephra libraries when I followed the doc verbatim.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you still have an old jar in the classpath of any one of your server. Please remove the stale jars and restart the cluster.
And, phoenix-[version]-server.jar should be enough in hbase/lib for Phoenix to work properly from server side.